# How to set UIImageView image added in viewForHeaderInSection and set in another Method

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

How to set `UIImageView` image added in `viewForHeaderInSection` and set in another Method.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(TQMultistageTableView *)mTableView
{
     return 4;
}

- (UIView *)mTableView:(TQMultistageTableView *)mTableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 90)];
    header.layer.backgroundColor    = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    header.layer.masksToBounds      = YES;

    UILabel *sectionTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, self.view.frame.size.width - 110, 70)];
    sectionTitleLabel.text = [sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section];
    sectionTitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    sectionTitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue" size:15];
    sectionTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    sectionTitleLabel.contentMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    [header addSubview:sectionTitleLabel];

    UIImageView *locationImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 90, 0, 90, 90)];
    locationImageView.image = [locationImageArray objectAtIndex:section];
    locationImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    [header addSubview:locationImageView];

    UILabel *sectionLineLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, header.frame.size.height - 1, self.view.frame.size.width, 1)];
    sectionLineLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [header addSubview:sectionLineLabel];

    discloserImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(locationImageView.frame.size.width - 50, 0, 40, 40)];
    discloserImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"down-arrow.png"];
    discloserImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    discloserImageView.tag = section;
    [locationImageView addSubview:discloserImageView];


    return header;
}

- (void)mTableView:(TQMultistageTableView *)mTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectRow ----%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
}

#pragma mark - Header Open Or Close

- (void)mTableView:(TQMultistageTableView *)mTableView willOpenHeaderAtSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Open Header ----%d",section);

//    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = [self mTableView:mTableView viewForHeaderInSection:section];

    UIView *headerView = [self mTableView:mTableView viewForHeaderInSection:section];
    [[[headerView subviews] objectAtIndex:1] subviews];
    NSLog(@"HeaderView :%@",headerView);

    for (UIImageView *imageView in [[[headerView subviews] objectAtIndex:1] subviews]) {
    if ([ imageView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"up-arrow.png"];
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wht is the issue you are facing with above code ? Did you try making the imageview as a property and then change it ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Unable to change the UIImageView image on selection

Answer (score 0):

In your code your header is not a `UIImageView` so your condition `if ([header isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])` will never be true. Indeed, you add your `UIImageView` as a subview of a `UIView`.

What you can do instead is :

```
if ([[header subviews][0] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
{
    UIImageView *imageViewChange =(UIImageView *) imageView;
    imageViewChange.image = [UIImage imageName@"downArrow.png"];
}
```

**Edit :**

According to your edit, I think your best bet is to make your `UIImageView` a property as follows :

```
@interface YourViewController () {
    UIImageView *imageViewChange;
}
```

and use it like that :

```
imageViewChange.image = [UIImage imageName@"downArrow.png"];
```

Comment: if image view taken globally then its change last index section image.!